# Creating jQuery-ui datepicker with Broadcast Months, not working in IE

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I need the datepicker to be in broadcast months, and I figured out how to do it without editing the code. It works in most cases so far but I'm having issues.

First off, my workaround is this:
I have `showOtherMonths:true, changeOtherMonths:true` which will get me the entire first week of the broadcast month. The first week of the next month is also shown, so this is what I'm doing to remove it (without removing the last week of a month that ends on Sunday)

```
$(function() {
    $(document).bind("click keypress", function(){
        // find "1" listed in outside month and hide the row
        $("table.ui-datepicker-calendar tbody td.ui-datepicker-other-month").filter(function(){
             return $.text([this]) == '1';
        }).closest("tr").hide();
        // remove styling that differentiates outside month
        $(".ui-priority-secondary").removeClass("ui-priority-secondary");
    });
});
```

[Working in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hcyQF/)

This works in Firefox and Chrome, but in IE8 (in compatibility mode) this only trims the last row when first opened. If you click to another month within the datepicker, you have to click the input box again or click on the datepicker background for the block of code above to fire.

I've tried unsuccessfully to call the same code with the `onChangeMonthYear` section but, from everything I can tell, in IE this code runs before the calendar is redrawn with the new month, meaning it's useless in this sense.

Also, I have `changeMonth: true, changeYear: true` and when changing the select menus, the block of code above does not run in ANY browser and I haven't found a workaround.

If I can get past these last roadblocks it would be something that anyone can use to show broadcast months without having to modify jquery-ui.js so they can use code hosted by google, etc.

Thanks!

Comment: Ahhh JSFiddle doesn't even work in IE8 anymore

Comment: Oh no, I didn't realize that. I use Firefox or Chrome for everything because IE is so insufferable...  
Is there something I can use that is compatible with IE?